# Uniform integrability and stochastic dominance

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-integrability

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables, and $Y$ a integrable random variable with
> $$\sup P(|X_n| \ge a) \le P(Y \ge a),$$
> for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $(X_n)$ is uniformly ntegrable.

This may be a stupid question, but I am having doubts if my solution is correct.

Since $P(|X_n| \ge a) \le P(Y \ge a)$ for all $n$, we have

$$\sup E(|X_n| ; |X_n|>a)=\sup \int_a^{\infty}xdF_{|X|}\le \int_a^{\infty}xdF_{Y}(x).$$

Since $Y$ is integrable, the limit when $a\rightarrow \infty$ is $0$.

Is my reasoning correct? If the dominance was pontual and not stochastic, I am certain of how to prove the result, but I'm not sure in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. The best way to go about this is using the [Darth Vader Rule](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/1030150905-M-O-W.pdf).
Applied here, it gives us that
$$E(|X_n|1_{|X_n| \geq a})= \int_a^\infty P(|X_n|\geq a)dx \leq \int_a^\infty P(|Y|\geq a)dx = E(|Y|1_{|Y|\geq a}).$$

Comment: Thanks, @Anon! I simply forgot this rule completely!